# reset index counter to include only selected elements

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have following html:

```
<div>something</div>
<div>something</div>
<div>something</div>
<div class="pick">something</div>
<div>something</div>
<div class="pick">something</div>
```

I need to write jquery that will return index number of selected elements not related to siblings though.

As in this piece of code, will return #3 for first occurrence of `pick` class, but what I am aiming for is #0 and #1 for the next one:

```
$(".pick").each(function() {
 alert( $(this).index() );
})
```

Is that possible to achieve??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index is first parameter passed to your function in `each()` call:

```
$(".pick").each(function(index,Element) {
 alert(index);
})
```

more info here: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".pick").each(function(a, b) {
    console.log("The index is:" + a);
    console.log("The element is: " + b);
})
```